# Move footnote in Pages 09?

Tags: iwork, iwork-pages, footnote

Is it possible to move all of my footnotes to the end of my document in Pages '09? I want to have a reference at the end of my document, like a bibliography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to convert footnotes to endnotes, but you cannot have endnotes and footnotes in the same document.

From the Pages '09 Help:

> **Converting Footnotes to Endnotes and
> Vice Versa**
>
> In a word processing
> document, you can change all the
> footnotes in a document into endnotes,
> or all the endnotes into footnotes.
> You can also convert all document
> endnotes to section endnotes and vice
> versa. However, you can’t mix endnotes
> and footnotes in the same document.
>
> To convert footnotes to endnotes and
> vice versa: In the Document pane of
> the Document inspector, change the
> setting in the Footnotes & Endnotes
> pop-up menu